# How to change Standard Application label text in UI5 dynamically in view controller

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

i am extending SAP standard HCM Application and standard field(STRAS) label coming from ODATA is 'House Number and Street' but i want to change and assign new label text 'Address Line 1' in UI5 View controller at runtime instead of copying standard ODATA and creating custom ODATA for this small change.

Note : Label is not bound through i18n Model in standard Application

```
<!-- Street / STRAS -->
<Label text="{/#Address10/Street/@sap:label}" id="lblStreet" labelFor="txtStreet" visible="{FieldStates>/STRAS/Visible}"/>
<Text id="txtStreet" text="{Street}" visible="{FieldStates>/STRAS/Visible}"/>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: It looks like the fields are hard coded. So why're you using the OData label instead of "Address Line 1" for your label in your XML?
`<Label text="Address Line 1" id="lblStreet" visible="{FieldStates>/STRAS/Visible}" />`

Comment: Thank You Alex for your response ...Actually this is Standard Application View and i don't have any option to change Standard View XML in extension application , ALSO don't want to change label at ODATA level for this small change(As mentioned above) . that's a reason the only way i can change Label 'Address Line 1' at runtime and i don't know how to change this label at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a [Controller Extension](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/08608efbe1864607a80fb7c41a9645e5).

You just need to add the following code in your manifest.json file inside the `"sap.ui5"` object:

```
"extends": {
    "component": "Standard App Namespace",
    "extensions": {  
        "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": {
            "standard.namespace.controller.ControllerName": {
                "controllerName": "my.namespace.ControllerNameExt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace the namespaces with the correct ones for your use case.

In the controller implementation you can add ([check is page for details on creating the controller](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/b0b14bf4dcdb476fb0d63877c1beff7c)):

```
onInit: function() { 
   this.getView().byId("lblStreet").setText("my new label"); 
}
```

Comment: Thank You Jorge for you response , i did try above view modification but it didn't work , as mentioned in documentation above modification is restricted only with view visible property , any other suggestion please ?

Comment: @AbdulQayyum, I just edited my answer, this should work for you.

Comment: Hi Jorge ,I already try below code but its not working ..                        
 .onBeforeRendering: function(oEvent) {
var lbltxt = this.getView().byId("lblStreet").getText();
if(lbltxt !== null) {
var lblNewtxt = "Address Line 1";
this.setView().byId("lblStreet").setText(lblNewtxt);
} }

Comment: @AbdulQayyum Is it possible to create local annotations file and apply it in the extension project? If so, replace the OData label with i18n text via annotation

Comment: @AbdulQayyum, If it is not working you can try to change the label in the service metadata by enhancing the *_MPC_EXT class of the project.